# After effects imports different pictures to same output

Tags: after-effects

I've imported 3 different pics that all are different when I look at them in Windows Explorer.

[image: image files in Windows Explorer]

However, when I put them in an After Effects composition, they all appear as the same picture.

[image: images in after effects]

I've tried importing them 1 by 1 and multiple file import. All three of these images came from an Illustrator file that I exported at the same time.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try this: turn off visibility of layer 5.  What changes?

Comment: If you double click the files in your project window do they look different in the footage window?

Comment: Instead of importing as jpgs, try importing as pngs. After effects
seems to bug out on jpgs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue arises because of the naming of your files. When images have a number attached at the end of their names, after-effects assumes that you're importing an image sequence. Thus, it imports each "image" as a sequence, consisting of all 3 images. When you import your files, try unchecking the box that says "import as image-sequence".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was as follows: I dragged and dropped the file in the project window. Then, right click the file which was "duplicated" and click on "Replace material". Apparently something went wrong when importing the file.

Answer (score 0):

same to me. to fix that issue, try to edit one by one picture in the folder using Paint Software, than save it. If nothing happen in after effect try to "right click then Reload the Image". It works to me. but it also wasting time if you have a lot of picture.